# Wanted to enable multi read region for azure cosmosdb account only if i am creating that for PROD environment (ARM Template)

Tags: json, azure, azure-rm-template

I am creating Azure cosmosdb account using ARM template. wanted to enable multi read region for cosmosdb only if the environment name is "PROD". i am using the same template across all my other environment.

any suggestions. refer to the below sample script: Highlighted location should only be used if my environment name is prod.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "environmentName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "dev,dev1,qa,prod,etc"
      }
    },
    -------------------
    --------------------
    -------------------

"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
      "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "Environment": "[parameters('environmentName')]",
        "Project": "DevOps",
        "CreatedBy": "ARMTemplate",
        "description": "Azure Cosmos DBName"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
        "databaseAccountOfferType": "[variables('cosmosdbOfferType')]",
        "locations": [
          {
            "locationName": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "failoverPriority": 0
          },
          **{
            "locationName": "Central US",
            "failoverPriority": 1
          }**
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities here including logical functions, deployment conditions or even passing in the regions as a parameter that could help solve the particular situation you have.

The most flexible option would be to pass the regions into the script by a parameter. This would allow it to be more flexible for reuse, in case environment names change or new ones are added. Also it would not be reliant on having a specific environment name set and would give more flexibility for its use. You can then easily setup the correct regions to be passed through in your deployment pipeline or parameter files for each environment.

If you don't want to do down that route there are other options such as using conditions to selectively deploy a resource with the correct setup. For your example this would lead to code duplication as you would need to have the resource elements twice with different setup and a condition tag that determined which one is run. This is not ideal due to the code duplication but might be useful on certain occasions.

Finally there is also the option of using Logical Functions to generate the locations required. This is similar to passing the regions to the script but you would generate the regions required using a function. This is slightly less flexible than passing the regions into the script but if you really need to set this up from a environment name this would probably be the way to go.

I have described each of the options above in a little more detail below with a few script examples. Please note the examples have not been tested so there may be typos or minor amends needed but they should generally be along the lines of what you need.

### Passing regions to the template

Using this method you would have something similar to the following. Add a regions array as part of your parameters. e.g.

```
  "regionsList": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "Central US",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Comma separated region list"
  }
},
```

You could then have a variable setup to generate your list of locations using the copy function to dynamically set the locations based on the list passed in. e.g.

```
"variables": {
"regionArray": "[split(parameters('regionsList'), ',')]",
"locations": {
  "copy": [
    {
      "name": "values",
      "count": "[length(variables('regionArray'))]",
      "input": {
        "locationName": "[variables('regionArray')[copyIndex('values')]]",
        "failoverPriority": "[copyIndex('values')]"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Once that is setup you only need to reference the variable within the locations property on the resource e.g.

```
 "locations": "[variables('locations').values]",
```

so your resource section would look something similar to this if you go down that route

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
  "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "Environment": "[parameters('environmentName')]",
    "Project": "DevOps",
    "CreatedBy": "ARMTemplate",
    "description": "Azure Cosmos DBName"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "[variables('cosmosdbOfferType')]",
"locations": "[variables('locations').values]",
  }
} ]
```

### Deploy Conditions

For a conditional deployment you can setup a resource to have a deploy condition set on it. It works like an if statement so if the value is true it will deploy and if it is false it will not. In your case you would have something like this on the resource section itself.

```
"condition": "[equals(parameters('environmentName'), 'PROD')]"
```

As this is on the resource level though you would need to have your resource listed twice with different locations / setup and an opposite condition on each. So one setup with a condition of environment equal to PROD (this one with the additional location) and the other setup with an environment not equal to prod.

As mentioned above though this causes duplication and is not ideal and I would not go with it unless there are significant difference in the template for the prod environment and even then there are better ways.

### Logical Functions

Logical functions can allow you to do transforms on values before using them and include things like if statements. In this case you could use them to determine the locations required for your resource based on the environment name passed in. This is similar to the passing regions to the template but without actually passing the regions in. It is slightly less flexible due to that.

You could then have a variable setup to generate your list of locations using the copy function to dynamically set the locations based on the list passed in. e.g.

```
"variables": {
"regionsList" : "[if(equals(parameters('environmentName'), 'PROD'), 'East US,Central US','East US')]"
"regionArray": "[split(variables('regionsList'), ',')]",
"locations": {
  "copy": [
    {
      "name": "values",
      "count": "[length(variables('regionArray'))]",
      "input": {
        "locationName": "[variables('regionArray')[copyIndex('values')]]",
        "failoverPriority": "[copyIndex('values')]"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

Once that is setup you only need to reference the variable within the locations property on the resource e.g.

```
 "locations": "[variables('locations').values]",
```

so your resource section would look something similar to this.

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
  "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "Environment": "[parameters('environmentName')]",
    "Project": "DevOps",
    "CreatedBy": "ARMTemplate",
    "description": "Azure Cosmos DBName"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('cosmosDBName')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "[variables('cosmosdbOfferType')]",
"locations": "[variables('locations').values]",
  }
} ]
```

With all of these options its also good to understand what all of the features actually do / are for. Please see below for links to the docs around the features I mentioned above.

[ARM Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources?tabs=json)

[ARM Logical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical?tabs=json)

[ARM Deployment Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-conditions)